# how to add file open password to excel file by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have a VISUAL BASIC code that creates a copy of the EXCEL file in a different location.... i need a code to password protect the copied file in different location from opening by other users.

Comment: Share what you have so far. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The Workbook.SaveAs method includes the ability to add a password to the saved workbook. See [the Office Dev Center reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You the SaveAs method on the workbook and use the Password option

```
dim wb as workbook
```

rest of code

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:="your_filename", Password:="xxxxxx"
```